# Dynamic Dependent Select Box using jQuery, PHP and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to create two select boxes which are Manufacturer, Type and being dependent on the choice of another. The problem is second select box didn't show

```
Manufacturer table
|   manuf_id*   |   manuf_name   |
|--------------------------------|
|       1       |     Bandai     |
|       2       |   Kotobukiya   |
|--------------------------------|

Type table
|   id*   |    type    | manuf_id** |
|-----------------------------------|
|    1    |   Gundam   |      1     |
|    2    | PVC Figure |      1     |
|    3    | PVC Figure |      2     |
|-----------------------------------|
```

### add_product.php

---

```
<?php 
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM manufacturer");
    $stmt->execute();
    $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
?>
    <select class="ui fluid dropdown" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer">
        <option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>
        <?php
            if($rowCount > 0){
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['manuf_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['manuf_name'] ?></option>
        <?php
                }
            } else {
        ?>
            <option value="">Manufacturer Not Available</option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

`<select class="ui fluid dropdown" name="type" id="type"></select>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#manufacturer').change(function() {
        var manufID = $('#manufacturer').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"ajaxData.php?",
            data:"manuf_id="+manufID,
            success:function(data){
                $("#type").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

### ajaxData.php

---

```
<?php
include '../config/config.php';

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM type WHERE manuf_id = ".$_GET['manuf_id']."");
    $query->execute();

    $rowCount = $query->rowCount();

    if($rowCount > 0) {
        echo '<option value="5">Select type</option>';
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['type'].'</option>';
        }
    }
```

?>

I can't really figure out why it isn't working and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of dependency are you trying to create exactly?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Can you narrow down the problem a little more?

Comment: type `<select></select>`dependent from manufacture value.

Comment: @Difster i didn't get error message, [DEMO](http://demos.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/)

Comment: Have you checked the console output in your browser?

Comment: @Difster yes, and there's nothing. I completely make like the demo

Comment: Are you getting any data returned to after the query? It's really hard to nail down where the problem is since I obviously don't have access to your database.

Comment: @Difster I have, I already add two tables of my database which I used to those code.

Comment: In jquey `method : post` and in php `@_GET`. ?

Comment: @OldPadawan I'm sorry, I forget to change before post it

Comment: @F.Wullur : what about adding error_reporting in your php file and see if any error occurs ?

Comment: Nothing wrong in the ajax part, From the given demo link its working fine, why cant you go with the demo

Comment: @OldPadawan I use `errorInfo()` and I don't get any error.

Comment: the link provided for the demo works, so I can get for now why you have an error somewhere else... and beside post/get (that you corrected), it all seems fine. weird...